# Numbering repetetiv IDs in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe are several patient IDs and some patients appear several times in the dataframe, which is correct. Now the patients need to get a number of the times they appear in the dataframe.

Example:

[image: 1]

Wanted:

[image: 2]

How can I get the occurrence number of the IDs?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df['Occurence'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
df
    ID  Data    Occurence
0   123 asd     1
1   123 qwe     2
2   451 cvb     1
3   784 tds     1
4   784 äkh     2
5   784 ijh     3
```

Comment: @MoritzUthe, if it works, can you please accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' mark next to it.